# Right using of ExifInterface in Android?

Tags: android, orientation, exif

I have this code in my Android app but in some devices such as LG F60 some photos made in application like Retrica are not shown in right rotaion.

```
        exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

        int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix ();
        boolean flip = false;
        switch (exifOrientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                flip=true;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                matrix.postRotate(0);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
                flip=true;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                flip=true;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
                flip=true;;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                break;
        }

        if (flip){
            matrix.postScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);
        }

        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

Does anyone has idea what is the problem?